# What happens when I give input as a string into an array which has size less than the string?

Tags: arrays, c, string

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    char w[3];
    scanf("%s",w);
    printf("%s\n",w);
    return 0;
}
```

For example, if I give a string 'Goods' which has 5 characters. But my array will accommodate only 2 characters and a \0. I got output as 'Goods' why?

Comment: You invoke *Undefined Behavior* writing beyond the end of your array. You cannot use `scanf()` to read into an array without also using the *field-width* modifier to protect your array bounds, e.g. `scanf ("%2s", w)` -- otherwise using `"%s"` is no safer than `gets()`. See [Why gets() is so dangerous it should never be used!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/3422102)

Comment: You'll write past the bounds of the array.  It's undefined behavior.  Possible outcomes are a segmentation fault, variables mysteriously changing their values, or in some cases you might not notice anything.  Just don't do it.

Comment: *"my array will accommodate only 4"* - your array will only accomodate **2**, plus the `\0` terminator which is automatically added by `scanf`.

Comment: effectively a dupe of good ol' [Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior)

Comment: Always better to take user input with `fgets()`, e.g. `char w[3]; if (fgets (w, sizeof w, stdin)) puts (w);` That limits you to reading no more than `2` characters plus the nul-terminating character into `w`. Also, *Don't Skimp on Buffer Size!*. Better to have 10,000 characters too many than 1 character too few. Literally hundreds of answers on this site about how to correctly handle user-input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have input overflow the buffer you pass. This will invoke *undefined behavior*. This behavior could be nothing on the moment or crash the application much later. You could have segment violation and more adverse effects.

To avoid that, you should use `fgets()` to read a string and then `sscanf()` to parse it. `fgets()` takes the size of the buffer as argument and prevent the buffer overflow.

Comment: Or use the correct specifier in `scanf` to limit the number of characters allowed for the size of the char array:  `%2s`